# Angular 6:Change array item in localStorage

Tags: arrays, angular6, angular-local-storage

I want to change Object property in local storage. The object will be like this

```
appID: {"userid":0,"username":null,"password":null,"saltPassword":null,"kraPassword":null,"kraPasskey":null,"panNumber":"BTRGH8774L","dob":"20/05/1980","address1":"24, New Palasia","address2":"Near vvds","address3":"dvdd","city":"","state":"","pincode":452001,"firstname":"Ramesh","middlename":"","lastname":"Patidar","fathername":"dvdvd","mothername":"vdsddvdsvdsvdsd","maritalStatus":null,"gender":1,"aadharNumber":"741204513909","mobile":"9479897412","email":"dvdsv@bha.com","token":null,"customerId":1,"strDob":null,"ekycApplicationId":1,"stage":"UPLOAD DOCUMENT","dd":null,"mm":null,"yyyy":null,"updatedAt":"26/10/2018","filter":null,"country":null,"stageId":null,"companyName":null,"openLayout":true}
```

Like Just want to change value of "mothername" from  array and add new value.

Comment: It is an object. Where is the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't edit the local storage value after it is saved but you can get it back, store it in an object, edit the desired property of object then save it again in the local storage.

```
let item =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
item['mothername']='New value';
localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item));
```

Don't forget to stringifying it on saving as local storage only save strings and parsing it in object when getting.

Answer (score 0):

One line approach using the new spread operator:

```
localStorage.setItem('appID', 
    JSON.stringify(
    { ...JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('appID')), 
      ...{ 'mothername': 'Mommy' }})
);
```